# AngularJS Conditional attributes from data

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a AngularJS app to render forms dynamically from a generic for definition data structure.  So the form details (including all validation rules, data types etc) are defined in a database and a single AngularController should "draw" the form.

For background - here is the rough structure of the defiintion:

```
Form 
   Sections
      Fields
```

It works fine - but I have a problem when adding attributes to the `<input>` element on the form based on the definition. So for example, lets say field1requires a min and max length validation, but field 2 does not.  This is achieved by adding the ng-minlength and ng-maxlength attributes to the input element for field1 and NOT adding these to the input element for field2.

Some googling sugested that the recently removed ng-attr directive might have been a sollution - but since its removed, I am stuck?

```
<ng-form name="frmTSFApp">

  <uib-tabset>

    <uib-tab ng-repeat="aSection in tsf3fd.section track by aSection.ukey"
             index="aSection.display_order"
             heading="{{aSection.display_label}}">

      <ng-form name="frmSection{{aSection.display_order}}">


         <div ng-repeat="aField in aSection.fields track by aField.ukey"
              class="form-group"
              ng-class="getFormClass(frmSection{{aSection.display_order}}[aField.data_name],aField)">

           <label class="control-label">{{aField.field_label}}</label>

               <input ng-required="{{aField.require_kind == 'R'}}" 
                      type="text" 
                      class="form-control" 
                      ng-model="tsf3fd.model[aField.data_name]" 
                      name="{{aField.data_name}}" />

       </ng-form>

   </uib-tab>

  </uib-tabset>
</ng-form>
```

The above snippet is what we use to render the form - so the ng-required attribute works nicely, since its always there and its value can be resolved from the expression.  For each field we "know" all the validations we need to add (ng-minlength or ng-pattern etc etc) but not sure how to do this?

In psuedo code I would like something like this "inside: the input element:

```
if (aField.validations.minmax) 
{
   ng-minlength = "{aField.validations.minmax.min}" 
   ng-maxlength = "{aField.validations.minmax.max}"  
}
```

Hope my explanation makes sense.

I am starting to doubt my approach - it seems a simpler approach is to render the "literal" form markup externally through something like XSLT from the deffinition data. We have done this and it works fine, but I thought working directly from the data would be so "cool" and would simplify the process.

Anyway - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If all are `type=text` (as seems in your code), why not simply adding all the validations? angular will ignore the ones with empty values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use:

```
<input
  ng-required="{{aField.require_kind == 'R'}}"
  ng-minlength="{{aField.validations.minmax ? aField.validations.minmax.min : '' }}"
  ng-maxlength="{{aField.validations.minmax ? aField.validations.minmax.max : '' }}"
  type="text" 
  class="form-control" 
  ng-model="tsf3fd.model[aField.data_name]" 
  name="{{aField.data_name}}" />
```

Setting `ng-minlength` or `ng-maxlength` to empty string has the same effect as not setting them.

Comment: Geez thats just perfect!!  Will test like this - but I am assuming it will work! Thank you.